# Function is returning the wrong value for floats. How do I fix?

Tags: visual-c++

The function int SpecialTriangles is not returning the correct values or just not working in general.

```
#include iostream
#include stdlib.h
#include string
#include cmath

using namespace std;

 float SL; // Short Leg
 float LL; // Long Leg
 float H; // Hypotenuse

 int SpecialTriangles() {

 SL = H / 2 && LL/sqrt(3); //Short Leg
 LL = sqrt(3)*SL; //Long Leg
 H = SL * 2; //Hyptoenuse

 return H, LL, SL;
 }

 int main() {

    cin >> SL;

  cout << H << endl ;


  system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

What I want it to do is when I put in say 5 for the short leg, then I want it to give 10 for H and 8.66025403784 for Long Leg.
Currently it just gives 0

Comment: Your code is missing quite a few `<` and `>`, and it isn't just a quotation problem.

Comment: Also `&&` is for logic, not for math.  Since the user inputs the short leg, you should not assign to it at all.

Comment: You are not even calling `SpecialTriangles`. You just print variable `H` that was never assigned to, and retains its original value of zero.